# problem by deleting new plugin installed inside the WordPress after any heroku app sleeping

Tags: wp-query

I have installed [this repo](https://github.com/elasa-Sites/wordpress-ja-pg4wp2-heroku) inside my Heroku app as you can see here:

https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com

By user id:

> ss

and password (for more information to check or log needed):

> n6RF1TSNrNkA!%q%o%9R18Td

by using this commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/elasa-Sites/wordpress-ja-pg4wp2-heroku
    r=$RANDOM; echo $r
    heroku create ss-wp$r --ssh-git --stack cedar-14
    heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev -a ss-wp$r # -a <app Name> which here ss-wp12 is appname

heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter -a ss-wp$r # -a <app Name> which here ss-wp@r is


heroku config:set AUTH_KEY='^%RH5z>.rM=9A+oH(6n,`+F99Z|3V@_ArpWy%{;+y|pFcCuKwl/<VP!#4oJ0+p2t' \
SECURE_AUTH_KEY='(<ofl_w;1k(tpsPF<].GW|p@rq|=0Mc<d~u[N8S!1C|{obdleN{+1&(;/mTTD0yh' \
LOGGED_IN_KEY='Thwf<)Ey^9EdtpxD?Z5TlO9-Pc|v)~La1BBRPk=Ey|%jPUc%A!SxVo6lxQ6uitK ' \
NONCE_KEY='BNx YjS{|[jtE,eHXh.m0{F=86uW<92),uU8}Yk)dz)j@bXqj@mEt!q|^.HU-<<w' \
AUTH_SALT='y1CFU=<RNO5Y_Io-}aovd}L:o-I{HdNMrt/=RR peqTn/%_@#U3uD^~]=8#z(`a' \
SECURE_AUTH_SALT='Ez~bty^ZCop.RV_)&zVb3:U MeDx1+m>Yz@m#>M5wpIk|5hoRQ~Z&m`r mJd69(U' \
LOGGED_IN_SALT='~R]Xaq<WE-j9Bc-ggAhQZdE|p]q bBolv$]YXjIu:7P;/)WP}R3Ys,*>%4Eqv[,/' \
NONCE_SALT='KR~5 NWctd2l^f>(f9~oxhMT?I7JcTM]^>NEzKZL.U+9yc^2hZujh~PALNs$Vdua' -a ss-wp$r  # -a <app Name> which here ss-wp@r is

echo "USERNAME:CRYPT PASSWORD" > .htpasswd
    git init
    git add .
    git remote add origin https://git.heroku.com/ss-wp$r.git
    #git config user.name "someone"
    #git config user.email "someone@someplace.com"
    git commit -am "start"
    git checkout -b production
    heroku git:remote -a ss-wp$r
    #heroku stack:set heroku-18 --remote origin
    git push heroku production:master
```

But the problem is restarting and deleting new plugin installed inside the WordPress  after any don't using the app for some hours ans after waking up by new request to the site, that is needs to reinstalling  again.
you can see here:
[image]
here is the last logs after waking up the repo now:

```
2019-12-05T21:44:51.535588+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=f11aa1f3-88ec-4a5a-b44d-21984d006eec fwd="2.182.123.165" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=91ms status=400 bytes=510 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:44:51.530689+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.183.55 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:44:51 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=WPvivid" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:44:51.590658+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.241.211 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:44:51 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=WPvivid" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:44:51.584369+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=d4c4f14a-8c89-47e9-8abc-c0c0affa4f5b fwd="2.182.123.165" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=126ms status=400 bytes=510 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:44:53.661743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=updraft_ajax&subaction=activejobs_list&nonce=cdf0baf8ab&downloaders=" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=d1655d36-ad84-4544-875b-933828b748e7 fwd="2.182.123.165" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=94ms status=400 bytes=407 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:44:53.662881+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.183.55 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:44:53 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=updraft_ajax&subaction=activejobs_list&nonce=cdf0baf8ab&downloaders= HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=updraftplus" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:44:55.513728+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=084effce-852e-4fb9-a573-b7b785cabfde fwd="2.182.123.165" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=73ms status=400 bytes=510 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:44:55.535404+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=13276588-4e37-4c3a-a9d3-0a29015fa44a fwd="2.182.123.165" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=78ms status=400 bytes=510 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:44:55.513166+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.183.55 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:44:55 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=WPvivid" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:44:55.533462+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.241.211 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:44:55 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=WPvivid" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:44:59.641359+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=fc32c0b4-4fe7-4c53-9c81-6554a6bc5bf8 fwd="212.103.48.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=160ms status=400 bytes=510 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:44:59.675595+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=updraft_ajax&subaction=activejobs_list&nonce=cdf0baf8ab&downloaders=" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=4eee086f-1741-4443-b776-fc7800185dfe fwd="212.103.48.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=156ms status=400 bytes=407 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:44:59.675639+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=2ec7ab92-e3c7-4d6e-bd87-9a614a9fef7c fwd="212.103.48.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=171ms status=400 bytes=510 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:44:59.639339+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.103.37 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:44:59 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=WPvivid" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:44:59.675355+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.213.124 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:44:59 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=WPvivid" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:44:59.682888+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.123.249.13 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:44:59 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=updraft_ajax&subaction=activejobs_list&nonce=cdf0baf8ab&downloaders= HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=updraftplus" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:45:03.604846+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=3729fe16-e938-4725-b9fc-96d7b08a78fa fwd="212.103.48.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=147ms status=400 bytes=510 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:45:03.575621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=0934309b-f047-407c-a55e-e2135f8b61af fwd="212.103.48.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=91ms status=400 bytes=510 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:45:03.578798+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.123.249.13 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:45:03 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=WPvivid" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:45:03.606606+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.103.37 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:45:03 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=WPvivid" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:45:05.612284+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.213.124 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:45:05 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=updraft_ajax&subaction=activejobs_list&nonce=cdf0baf8ab&downloaders= HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=updraftplus" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:45:05.616701+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=updraft_ajax&subaction=activejobs_list&nonce=cdf0baf8ab&downloaders=" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=f38872e3-7420-4834-b980-e6ba71bb9094 fwd="212.103.48.115" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=85ms status=400 bytes=407 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:45:07.629102+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=94152c5d-8630-4f6c-bc22-8c38e57b5109 fwd="212.103.48.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=109ms status=400 bytes=510 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:45:07.630826+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.123.249.13 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:45:07 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=WPvivid" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:45:08.603276+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=aee81c91-f043-4af9-a89d-b85863aa4a0d fwd="212.103.48.115" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=99ms status=400 bytes=510 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:45:08.604800+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.103.37 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:45:08 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=WPvivid" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:45:09.557561+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/wp-cron.php" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=0fec7f9f-1ce3-4635-9b3f-dc472380cedd fwd="212.103.48.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=82ms status=200 bytes=150 protocol=https
2019-12-05T21:45:09.558427+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.213.124 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:45:09 +0000] "GET /wp-cron.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=WPvivid" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:45:09.590081+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.123.249.13 - - [05/Dec/2019:21:45:09 +0000] "GET /wp-cron.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - "https://ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=WPvivid" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
2019-12-05T21:45:09.590005+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/wp-cron.php" host=ss-wp25856.herokuapp.com request_id=12971149-d370-40bc-9544-e34ede8074cf fwd="212.103.48.115" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=105ms status=200 bytes=150 protocol=https
 Autoscroll
```

According this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59020673/why-do-my-app-on-heroku-restart-itself-after-sleeping-on-free-dyno-heroku-apps/59029388?noredirect=1#comment104356645_59029388, and this answer:

> This sounds like your applications state (which I assume is what you
>   mean by configuration ) is being reset each time the Dyno boots due to
>   the ephemeral filesystem being used, see
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem for a
>   better explanation. You may also find
>   https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted
>   helpful. Basically, any data stored to the hard drive will not survive
>   when the Dyno reboots (which happens on every deploy, as well as every
>   24 hours). Instead, you should use cloud storage like Amason AWS S3.

dose this means the Heroku default is going to delete all new files added to repo after sleeping and waking up the app?

So if this is true, is it possible to upload all data and files to new storage space like GitHub ( or your suggestion), to do it before sleeping timeout (approximate 30 min no request) ?

could we use:

```
 heroku login
 heroku git:clone -a <app-name>
 cd <app-name>
 heroku git:remote -a <app-name>
 git pull heroku master
```

command to grab all app files into another server or local storage to save the new changes added to word press site before going to sleep and erasing those data and push them to main GitHub repo to uploading to the app after waking up?

thanks for your attention.

Comment: I **strongly recommend** changing that password **immediately**. This is a public forum.

Comment: Thanks @Pat_j i know but this is a test site and it will be deleted after finding answers. SO i don't think have any risk for me,do am i right?

Comment: That's not something I can determine for you.

Comment: Even if it's a test site, it's available on the open web, and in the edit history of this question, it can never be used securely as a result

Answer (score 0):

You are using a version control/git based system, as a result you must add/remove plugins via `git`. You shouldn't use the built in updaters or plugin/theme installers, especially since Dynos are not persistent

As an aside, if you want to test out things, you can just use a local development environment, such as VVV/MAMP/Local/etc